# Git fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF

Tags: git

Добавляю в репозиторий файл, `git` ругается следующим образом:

> fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in Web/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js

говорю хорошо не проблема, делаю следующее

1. Открываю `bootstrap.js` в `Notepad++`;
2. Правка=>Формат Конца Строк=>Преобразовать в Win-формат (CRLF);
3. Сохраняю файл.

Делаю вновь `git add *.js`:

> fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in Web/Scripts/Bootstrap/bootstrap.js

`git` был настроен следующим образом:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf true
```

Подскажите, как необходимо настроить `git`, чтобы избавиться от данной ошибки?

Comment: ассоциация: http://stackoverflow.com/q/20168639/2110496

Answer (score 31, accepted):

скорее всего, в результате выполнения этого действия:

> 2. Правка=>Формат Конца Строк=>Преобразовать в Win-формат (CRLF);

в файле всё-таки остался хотя бы один «одиночный» символ <kbd>lf</kbd>.

---

> как необходимо настроить git что бы избавиться от данной ошибки?

совсем «избавиться» от сообщения можно, вернув значение по умолчанию:

```
$ git config --global core.safecrlf false
```

заменить же сообщение об ошибке на предупреждение можно так:

```
$ git config --global core.safecrlf warn
```

---

дополнительные сведения можно почерпнуть в [*man-странице git-config*](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

Comment: спасибо за ответ, на текущий момент в данном решении установил `autocrlf` в `false`. я тоже подумал о том что notepad++ что то пропустил но как узнать где я не придумал

Comment: если у вас есть «под рукой» операционная система *gnu/linux*, можно воспользоваться программой *hexdump* для просмотра файла в «шестнадцатиричном» виде: `$ hexdump -C файл | less`.

Comment: у меня Windows но в нем есть Far и возможно просмотреть в hex в нем тоже присутствует

Answer (score 6):

Если вы работаете в jetBrains idea:

1) внизу справа, увидите такой значок
[image: формат конца строк файла в idea]

Здесь вы можете поменять формат для текущего файла на `crlf`, а затем повторить `git push`

Вот полезная [ссылка по настройке проекта](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/configuring-line-separators.html)

2) Если хотите изменить формат всех файлов, то в верхнем меню идеи найдите:

File > Line Separators > CRLF.

Answer (score 1):

```
git config core.autocrlf input
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю настройки менять не стоит, сам использую такие же.

> Akela_wolf на Habr ([Git for Windows: работа с параметром core.autocrlf](https://habr.com/ru/post/703072/)):
> "Если коротко: в Windows надо всегда ставить autocrlf=true. Это означает что в репозитории всегда будет храниться LF. А при извлечении из репозитория - произойдет преобразование в CRLF. И это обеспечит консистентность если в будущем появится еще один разработчик, работающий в Linux или MacOS. Или если даже единственный разработчик вдруг возьмет макбук/установит Linux и т.д.
> Остальное - как правило ненужная гибкость, которая востребована если вы точно понимаете что и зачем делаете."

А чтоб ошибка "fatal: LF.." не появлялась, необходимо будет настроить редактор как уже здесь посоветовала [Julia Usanova](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/741885/325525).
В VS Code это делается так же просто.

Проверено - всё работает.

Ещё одно интересное исследование - [Использование Git. Параметр AutoCRLF](https://jenyay.net/Git/Autocrlf)

> Эксперимент третий.
> Для начала немного предыстории. Git я использую под Windows (сборку msysgit) для переноса исходников из дома на работу. Но иногда получалась ситуация, когда приношу измененные исходники в главном репозитории, делаю git pull, чтобы обновить исходники в рабочей копии, команда без проблем выполняется, но затем, если даже ничего не трогать, то некоторые файлы помечаются как измененные.
> Я долго не мог понять в чем дело, просмотр изменений по сравнению с предыдущей версией показывал, что якобы изменились все строки в файлах, причем сами на себя. Команда git reset --hard ничего не меняла, даже откат изменений с помощью git checkout -- <измененный файл> ничего не давал, файлы оставались помечены как измененные.
> Сразу закралась мысль о переводах строк, но повторить ситуацию в лабораторных условиях, чтобы точно определить когда такое происходит, удалось только недавно, также случайно нашлось решение этой проблемы, но вопрос почему это происходит до сих пор открыт.

Стоит иметь ввиду.