# Как с помощью Bracket git отправить на github файл index.html?

Tags: git, github

Я сделал всё по [инструкции](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVbbdCDBIbI&t=456s)

установил [brackets-git](https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git) расширение для редактора Brackets

Всё работает, кроме того что неактивна кнопка - "Commit" для файла index.html

Почему не получается запушить index.html на github?

Comment: Очень вас прошу, не используйте расширения и любые другие GUI-клиенты для базовых операций в git. Они только всё запутывают. Освойте командную строку, она простая и надёжная.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, с некоторым удивлением для себя обнаружил, что часто пользуюсь интерфейсом idea для коммитов. Удобно же)

Comment: @vp_arth ну я тоже посматриваю на раскраску файлов и строк в идее. Но судя по ридми, это расширение поддерживает далеко не все операции. Кстати, я им закинул смешной ПР: https://github.com/zaggino/brackets-git/pull/1333

Answer (score 3):

Расскажу по порядку  как появилась эта ошибка, и как удалось решить эту ситуацию.

Началось с того что я проходил задания на githowto.com/setup

Как уже сейчас выяснилось, я ввел параметры установки окончаний строк как этого требует задание и успешно забыл об этом.

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf true
```

Пройдя задания до 20 уровня, я начал заниматься другими делами. Потом случайно нашел видео на [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YVbbdCDBIbI&t=456s) про расширение Brackets git (мне нравиться этот редактор).

Сделал всё по инструкции, но по неизвестной мне причине была  неактивна кнопка - "Commit" для файла index.html.

Вернувшись в cmder я обнаружил следующую ошибку:

```
$ git add .
fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF in index.html
```

Мне повезло когда я загуглил её, и попал сразу на этот ответ - [Git fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474751/git-fatal-lf-would-be-replaced-by-crlf/653071#653071)

Вспомнив где я  менял эти параметры:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
git config --global core.safecrlf true
```

Я вернул эти значения по умолчанию.

В конечном итоге файл index.html [был успешно отправлен](http://i89.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0413/bd/63567f05503f930472a74a5780e972bd.png) на github.com