# Предупреждение - LF will be replaced by CRLF / The file will have its original line endings in your working directory

Tags: git

Вывод с предупреждением:

```
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyFirstMVC/MyFirstMVC/Controllers/PhonesController.cs.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyFirstMVC/MyFirstMVC/Models/ApplicationDbContext.cs.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
warning: LF will be replaced by CRLF in MyFirstMVC/MyFirstMVC/Models/Phone.cs.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
```

Из-за чего это и что делать или как этого избежать?

Comment: **4** связано с несогласованностью знака используемого для обозначения конца строки, в одном месте используется Windows style в другом Unix style. посмотрите [мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474751/179270)

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, надо было отдельно 4 разных вопроса создать.

Comment: @Bald Спасибо понял!

Comment: @A K Почему обширный? Вроде всё по одной теме?

Comment: на данном ресурсе принято задавать *конкретные вопросы*, у вас их 4 в одном, на каждый из них можно дать ответ и они не связаны между собой ничем кроме метки git

Comment: @Bald так как мне поступить, правит вопрос и создать ещё 4?

Comment: Лучше почитать основы Git использования на https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git или https://githowto.com/ru

Comment: да, отредактируйте исходный вопрос, оставив в нем один из пунктов, а прочие оформите отдельными вопросами. альтернатива удалить этот вопрос, почитать по ссылке выше и потом задавать что не понятно

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov Спасибо за ссылки! Но, там нет того что мне нужно.

Comment: При установки гит на одной из страниц установщика есть опции - что делать при несоответствии LFCR - и там три пункта - менять на LF, менять на CR, менять на CRLF и 4-тый - оставить без изменений. У вас 2-ва варианта - перебить гит (гит-клиент), и выбрать 4-тый пункт. 2) покопать опции гита, найти этот пункт и сказать ему пусть не трогает.

Comment: А возникло потому что выбрана опция проверять что перенос строки CRLF (по умолчанию скорее всего), а  в вашем файле LF без CR. Редакторы бывают под виндой в основном двух видов. Одни фигачат LFCR а другие LF без CR. Ваш  - второй вариант. LF - 13 код. СR=10.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/474751/178576

Comment: @alexander barakin  Спасибо, выше уже дали ссылку на этот ответ! Не знаю как пометить его как ответ! А, так вопрос закрыт!

Comment: @Bald да я вроде триуголничек нажал ! Или не так голосуют?

Comment: вот здесь все подробно расписано по этому вопросу https://jenyay.net/Git/Autocrlf

Comment: При такой же проблеме нашел решение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important).

Comment: При такой же проблеме нашел решение [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5834014/lf-will-be-replaced-by-crlf-in-git-what-is-that-and-is-it-important).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Git fatal: LF would be replaced by CRLF](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/474751/git-fatal-lf-would-be-replaced-by-crlf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В Windows и Unix системах перенос строки обозначается по-разному. В Windows - \r\n (crlf), в Unix - \n (lf). В связи с этим возникает проблема, git видет изменения в файлах репозитория, даже, если изменения в них вами не вносились. Единственное различие - окончание строки.
Для решения этой проблемы используются определенные настройки git
Для Windows:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf true
```

Что позволяет при сохранении файлов в репозиторий заменить crlf на lf и сделать обратную замену при извлечении файлов

Для Unix:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf input
```

Замена crlf на lf происходит только при записи в репозиторий

Собственно о замене окончания строк и говорят ваши warnings. А также о том, что кто-то позаботился о корректной настройки git

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2825829/6944845